# Can you access Store Visits via the Google Analytics Reporting API v4

Tags: api, google-analytics

I'm a python user and pretty new working with the Google Analytics API. I've been able to get Store Visit information (and break down by various dimensions) via GA's website, but haven't been able to figure out how to do so via the API. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

I have been to the bowels of the interwebs on topics around this as well- from what I can tell and by the lack of answers- I am thinking no. Workaround would be to use GA to schedule a reoccurring emailed xls report that a downstream reporting tool can ingest.